# Load GeoJson file to google maps - ERROR

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am trying to embed GeoJson file on google map api but its not showing me the json file on the map. The map is empty.
I've put the json file on my windows server (working with iis)
and the html page I wrote with notepad++

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
   #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   }

   marker{
   color:green;
   }
</style>
</head>



<body>
  <h3>My Google Maps Demo PLIZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</h3>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });


     // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
    map.data.loadGeoJson(
  'D:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++googlejson.json');



  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAYTSB-wjOrjVjPGazmGeGCLzUxKa_gmA8&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The json file

It looks like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "letter": "G",
      "color": "blue",
      "rank": "7",
      "ascii": "71"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [123.61, -22.14], [122.38, -21.73], [121.06, -21.69], [119.66, -22.22], [119.00, -23.40],
          [118.65, -24.76], [118.43, -26.07], [118.78, -27.56], [119.22, -28.57], [120.23, -29.49],
          [121.77, -29.87], [123.57, -29.64], [124.45, -29.03], [124.71, -27.95], [124.80, -26.70],
          [124.80, -25.60], [123.61, -25.64], [122.56, -25.64], [121.72, -25.72], [121.81, -26.62],
          [121.86, -26.98], [122.60, -26.90], [123.57, -27.05], [123.57, -27.68], [123.35, -28.18],
          [122.51, -28.38], [121.77, -28.26], [121.02, -27.91], [120.49, -27.21], [120.14, -26.50],
          [120.10, -25.64], [120.27, -24.52], [120.67, -23.68], [121.72, -23.32], [122.43, -23.48],
          [123.04, -24.04], [124.54, -24.28], [124.58, -23.20], [123.61, -22.14]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

UPDATE - I also try to put the json file on my cumputer but its still not OK

Comment: Your webserver isn't working. (`GET http://vmedu140.mtacloud.co.il/googlejson.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`)

Comment: Are U sure? because when I enter this addrress is working - http://vmedu140.mtacloud.co.il/googlejson.json

Comment: Not for me, I get `This site can’t be reached vmedu140.mtacloud.co.il took too long to respond.` for both.

Comment: also if I try in my local computer:                                
      map.data.loadGeoJson(
      'D:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++googlejson.json');                                              its not working

Comment: What does your javascript console say?

Comment: To test on your local computer, give your script a *relative path* to your file, ie. `path/to/file.json` and **not** `D:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++googlejson.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved! TNX

there was a problem with my server